# Getting Error 2714 while installing MSI file for web project generated from visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to create MSI file for my c#(.net) web application in visual studio 2013.
I have added web setup project template (installer project template) in my solution and configured it for my required project.After building solution I am bale to get the MSI file but while installing it, it is throwing Error: 2714. I searched and tried many things to solve it but the error still persists.

Could anyone help me with the Error 2714 in MSI installation.

Comment: The error means "Invalid value for default folder name: [2]." and should include the folder name, was it in the exact message text?

Comment: @PhilDW : Where to set the default folder name. I didn't set default folder , but still my MSI works fine if i restart the machine. After few hours it agains throw same error.PFB the exact error message-
The error code is 2714. The arguments are: APP/NEWBUSINESS/QUOTE/CONTROLLERS/|app/newbusiness/Quote/Controllers/

Comment: Any solution to this?